# max value from varchar date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to find max date from a table(mysql database). I am storing my date as varchar.

`select max(completion_date) from table_name` returns wrong value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c88f6/3

Comment: Fix the table to store the date using the proper types.  Then just use `max()`.

Comment: Use the date datatype.

Comment: mistake #1: storing as a varchar.  since your dates as strings, then STRING rules will apply for max/min decisions. your dates aren't in most-significant-first ordering, so you're getting EXACTLY what you asked for: the largest **STRING**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date time format you have in your fiddle (e.g. '12/19/2012 05:30 PM') then:

```
select max(STR_TO_DATE(completion_date, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p')) from test;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c88f6/15

It's unclear if you want to factor the time into your rankings or just the date. This example accounts for time too, but you can remove that part of the formatter if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to keep it as varchar not date.
But this will work for varchar:

```
SELECT completion_date
FROM test
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(completion_date, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC LIMIT 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c88f6/10

Comment: I want the max(completion_date)

Comment: SELECT MAX(completion_date)

Comment: yup above will give you max completion date because we are sorting it in descending order then limiting it to one output which will result in max value. Run it in fiddler you provided and you will see the correct output.

Comment: @Learner2011 please accept the answer if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  // Store dates
  $dates = array();
  // Loop through and transfer the result set
  foreach ($result as $row => $data) {
    $dates[$row] = $data['date'];
  }
  // Sort the array
  usort( $dates, "date_sort_function" );
  // Max is last date in array.
  foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $max = $date;
  }
?>
```

Well, something like that. It is a php script and all you have to provide is the sorting function which returns 0 if equal, 1 if older, and -1 if earlier.